# Leptonica apply threshold

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I am trying to use leptonica's pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold function but with little luck. I am not sure if I am doing it right but I am trying to take an UIImage (objective-C), apply the pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold and then convert back to UIImage. It crashes when I call pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold with the parameters I have passed in.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I have been struggling with this for 2 days and I think I am losing my mind. Thanks!

**CODE**

```
-(void)leptnoica:(UIImage *)image {

CGImageRef myCGImage = image.CGImage;
CFDataRef data = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(myCGImage));
const UInt8 *imageData = CFDataGetBytePtr(data);

PIX *myPix = (PIX *) malloc(sizeof(PIX));
myPix->w = (int)CGImageGetWidth (myCGImage);
myPix->h = (int)CGImageGetHeight (myCGImage);
myPix->d = (int)CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(myCGImage);
myPix->wpl =  (CGImageGetBytesPerRow (myCGImage)/4);
             // myPix->informat = IFF_TIFF;
myPix->informat= IFF_PNG;
myPix->data = (l_uint32 *) imageData;
myPix->colormap = NULL;
l_int32 one=300;
PIX *pixg;
PIX *pixB;

pixg = (PIX *) malloc(sizeof(PIX));
pixg=pixConvertTo8(myPix, 0);
l_float32 scorefract=0.1f;
pixOtsuAdaptiveThreshold(pixg, one, one, 0, 0, scorefract,NULL,&pixB);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always use the leptonica constructors (e.g., pixCreate()) and the leptonica accessors (e.g., pixGetDimensions()).  Never access any fields directly.  All accessors test arguments and are designed not to crash your program, even if you give bad input.  Look at some of the programs in the prog directory for examples of usage.

Second, the CGImage may have the bytes in a different order from leptonica, and it may have different pixel and line padding.  You need to understand both data formats and make the appropriate conversion.